# How to prove that width of general dirichlet series is given by this

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series

My instructor gave me this question for the assignment and I am not able to solve this.

> Prove that $ 0\leq \sigma_{a} -\sigma_{c} \leq L$, where $\displaystyle L=\limsup_{ n\to \infty}  \frac{\log n} {\lambda_n}$.

Here is some information about the general Dirichlet series:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series

So, I tried to use the formula of abscissa of convergence and abscissa of absolute convergence but that doesn't seem the right thing to do here.

So, can you please outline a proof as assignment might not be discussed due to ongoing pendamic situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Suppose $\sigma = \sigma_c + u$ with $u > L$. Show that $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n e^{-\lambda_n s}$$ converges absolutely.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you please elaborate on why should I consider the series  $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n e^{-\lambda_n s}$. Thanks!